# build elasticsearch bool query in java dynamically

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is there any way to build the elasticsearch bool query dynamically. In my application user may use multiple filters at a time. Its like, he may use 2 filters in one request and 3 filters for another request.I'm storing that filter details in hashmap. so based upon the user request the query should change by adding filters.

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                    .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("client_code",
                            "SSSS"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can iterate over your hashmap keys/values and build your bool query accordingly for each key/value pair you'll find:

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String key : hashmap.keySet()) {
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(key, hashmap.get(key)));
}
```

Comment: Yeah... Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Awesome you helped me a lot. Thanks